# clicking on dropdown content, dropdown getting hide

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, click, mouseclick-event

HTML code for dropdowns:

```
<ul>
 <li class="dropDownLink">
   Locality
   <ul class="dropDown">
     <li class="dropDown-row"><input tpye="text"></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropDownLink">
   Locality
   <ul class="dropDown">
     <li class="dropDown-row"><input tpye="checkbox"> Option 1</li>
     <li class="dropDown-row"><input tpye="checkbox"> Option 2</li>
     <li class="dropDown-row"><input tpye="checkbox"> Option 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

jquery Code to show dropdown:

```
$('.dropDownLink').on('click', function () {
  $('.dropDown').hide();
  $(this).children($('.dropDown')).show();
});
```

jQuery to hide dropdowns on clicking outside dropdown:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if(!$('.dropDownLink').is(e.target) && !$('.dropDown').is(e.target)) {
    $('.dropDown').hide();
  }
});
```

When clicking on document other than dropdown its working fine but clicking on content inside dropdown its hiding its parent dropdown. There are some form contents as well in dropdown like input textfield, checkboxes and links. Dropdown should not hide clicking on these elements inside dropdown.

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Ashwani, I have created a solution in my main answer.  I used the `$('*')` selector instead of the `$(document)`. I then built up a string of DOM elements related to the navigation menu so that I could exclude from being bound to the `on('click')` function. I hope this gets you there.  May God bless you.

Comment: [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ptg68gxc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with exact solution: The advice of super specific DOM element targeting still stands. [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ptg68gxc/)

```
var $dropShow = function showList() {
    $('.dropDownLink').on('click', function () {
        $('.dropDown').hide();
        $(this).children($('.dropDown')).show();
    });
};
var $navSelections = $('li.dropDown-row input, li.dropDown-row, ul.dropDown li.dropDown-row input, li.dropDownLink, ul li.dropDownLink');

var $bodyClick = function hideAll() {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        if (!$navSelections.is(e.target)) {
            $('.dropDown').slideUp(150);
        }
    });
};

$('.dropDownLink').not($navSelections).click($dropShow());
$('*').not($navSelections).click($bodyClick());
```

Pinpoint the pathing that you want the action to occur on only.  If it is only supposed to occur, for example on a div, then use `$('div.dropDownLink')`.  If it is only links in say, a navMenu that you want this functionality applied to, then you use `$('navMenu div.dropDownLink')`.  Essentially, the more accurate your selector the better the results will be.

If however, you would like to take the not so accurate approach you can use the `.not()` method to leave out very specific things.

```
var $parentOfDropDown = $('div#navMenu');
$('.dropDown').not($parentOfDropDown).hide();
```

Comment: Just used that as well but its not working. I updated my question with my HTML as well. Please have a look now if this could help.