# toggleClass is not working for onclick event

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet of code:

```
$('#app-store').find('.appEntry').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

The toggleClass does not work. The selector is right, and if I stop the debugger on the toggleClass line and run the "$(this).toggleClass("selected");" line in the Chrome Console, then it does toggle the class just like it should. What am I doing wrong here? I feel like it's something really stupidly obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: hemm..Dynamic content?

Comment: Can you put all the html and jquery code ?

Comment: If it is toggling in Chrome Console, it might not be this code that has the issue. Something might be wrong with the "selected" class.

Comment: Can you make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hmm, well that's interesting. When I make it a JS Fiddle with just the click event, then it works. There has to be something wrong with the surrounding JS. One weird thing I notice is that if I look at the Element view in the Chrome Console I can see that the class attribute of the element flashes when I click, so something is happening, but the class doesn't get added.

Answer (score 0):

You must more accurately specify your selector because there may be other surrounding DOM elements causing the click to bubble. More specifically,  call the tag and the ID and use a space to flow down the parent/children pathing.

Link to similiar issue and solution:

[clicking on dropdown content, dropdown getting hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765167/clicking-on-dropdown-content-dropdown-getting-hide/31765529?noredirect=1#comment51470894_31765529)